# json loads exception expected string or buffer python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse json files from huge JSON file (1.9GB) so i split them into chunks of 10MB (190 files).

in order to ease the process so i load them 80 files at a time and i put them into a list

i use this to iterate through the 80 files

```
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for f in filenames:
        function below
```

and this is the function to read file names with corrected path

```
dat = 'C:/Users/User/My Lab/Python/scripts/thesis/data_extractor/review/{file}'.format(file=f)
with open(dat) as data_file:
        for item in data_file:
                if len(item) > 1:
                        dict_review.append(item)
```

after the process is done, i iterate the list and parse them using json.loads

```
data = None
for row in dict_review:
        data = json.loads(row,'utf-8')
```

and thats where the exception happens

```
Unexpected error:  <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>
Reason:  expected string or buffer
```

i tried casting the row into string with str(row) but still returns the same exception.

i wonder what i did wrong, thanks!

SOLVED:

it was my mistake, actually the JSON was properly parsed, the problem is when i try to remove all funny characters with regex

```
re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ',data['votes']) 
to
re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ',str(data['votes']))
```

i need to cast the object into string

thanks!

Comment: The first part could use `glob` and be `for filename in glob.iglob("/some/path/*.ext")`, for example.

Comment: Also, you posted parts of your script, this lets us without enough context. Where does `dict_review` comes from, and what type is it? is it a dict or a list? And what happens between the second and third code blocks?

Comment: try to visualize the content of the row with `print('row=%r' % row)` before the `json.loads...` line. I'm sure you will be surprised.

Comment: @heltonbiker dict_review is a global variable and its a list. everything is fine, until it reaches the json.loads() which user3159253 mentioned and i found a "\n" inside of a json file, im going to check it out now

Comment: @user3159253 yes sir! i was surprised that i found an invalid json! thanks!

Comment: Looks like you're reading the file line by line, but each line is not a complete JSON entity (as it should be for your approach to work). It's still not possible to understand what do you mean by "chunks of 10MB" taken from "huge JSON file". Are you splitting a single file in smaller files, using file size as a parameter? This is confusing...

Comment: The `dict_review` you create is a list of strings.. `json.loads()` requires its first argument to be a single string. Besides that I don't think your whole approach to handling the large file is going to work because in general JSON files can't be parsed piecemeal like that.

Comment: if you would publish the script with the input data, I'm sure that now you'd have a complete working solution, not just 'guessings' of different levels of usability. Anyway, I'm glad to help.

Comment: wouldnt i be able to iterate through list of string and that would have json.loads to load a single string from the list? im still trying btw, ill let you know if it succeeds @martineau

Comment: currently the row prints out " 'json' " and json.loads still unable to recognize it because of the " ' " notation in there, trying to remove it with str.replace("'","") ill let you know if it succeed @user3159253

Comment: @heltonbiker the list contains of lines of json objects, so each line is a complete json object. i forgot to mention it up there

Comment: @keniz: demonstrate an example of input data and, well, problematic places. It's quite hard to guess what happens on your side.

Comment: @user3159253 solved it! it was a stupid mistake!

Comment: @martineau i was able to parse through 1.8GB json using this method.

Comment: Combining all the strings in the list into a single one should get rid of the `TypeError`. However, the fact that you were able to parse the whole file in pieces this way must be due to something special about its format, i.e. it has no JSON entities split across multiple lines and their entire definition happens to always end up in the same chunk, thereby avoiding the problem of one starting in one chunk but being finished in the lines of another — hence my comment about it not working _in general_.

Comment: I tried combining all of the list, but i get myself a memoryerror exception probably due to my workstation. and you're right, i was able to parse through them this way because each line is an object, so basically i have dozens of json objects within a single json file. thanks alot! @martineau

Comment: Sounds like what you have is improperly formatted JSON file. If there are dozens of separate json objects in it as you describe, then technically _they_ should be inside of some outermost container which was either another json dict-like object (with an associated key for each) or more likely a simple list. Either way this outer object would have to have been started in the very first chunk and terminated in the final one — i.e. not all in one chunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was my mistake, actually the JSON was properly parsed, the problem is when i try to remove all funny characters with regex

```
re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ',data['votes']) 
to
re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ',str(data['votes']))
```

i need to cast the object into string